# how to make left hand side navigation menu

Tags: jquery

Can somebody please guide me how to make left hand side navigation menu (left hand slider)with the help of (jQuery), using only single CSS and minimum JavaScript.

Please refer to this [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Slick-App-Like-Sliding-Menu-Plugin-With-jQuery-Mmenu/examples/basic.html).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do some homework for this?

Comment: It seems like the page you linked to in your question *is* the answer. What are you asking?

Comment: yes this is what i want but dis page is having lot of jscript nd css i want in a single css how can v do dat??

Comment: @user3632406 You can use this one also [http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/](http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/). Or try my answer

Comment: @user3632406 Please vote up my comment and check my answer as correct answer. Because, I know, my answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Don't ask question like this. First you have to try. Developer needs to try first. That is the shape of developers. We are knowledge seekers. :-D

Anyway! [TRY THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/zz5nk/). I also tried and learnt from my self.  You have to change some scripts as well as you want. Or you can use this [CSS TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/). Try to do best.

Here some Codes.

**HTML**

```
<header>
        <ul id="menu" class="jpanelMenu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a class="menu" link="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" link="/">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" link="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu" link="/">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="trigger">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="menu-trigger btn btn-default btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Menu
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">Yeshan App</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">Web Developer</div>
    </div>

<section id="contents">
    <p>I have another page call about.html. in that page I have contents inside the area div. Now, This functions are working fine in my localhost.</p>
    <p>Just I want to know is, when I click on the navigation menu. I want to hide the jPanelMenu as a result there website.</p>
    <a href="http://jpanelmenu.com/" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
        menu: '#menu',
        trigger: '.menu-trigger',
        duration: 600
    });
    jPM.on();

    $(".menu").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("link");
        //alert(url);
        //$( "#contents" ).fadeIn("slow").load(url+" #contents");
        $('#contents').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#contents').load(url+' #contents', function(){
                $('#contents').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
        jPM.close();
    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#jPanelMenu-menu {
    overflow-y:hidden !important;
}
#trigger { padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #000; }
.jpanelMenu { list-style: none; padding: 0px;}
.jPanelMenu li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    color:#FFF;
}
.jPanelMenu li a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You have to change some script also. Suggestion http://jpanelmenu.com/.

If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.